# Tide with terrain in OpenSim

Tags: c#

I want to recreate Atlantis' disappearance in OpenSim for school. So far I only managed to get the water to rise. I now want the terrain to go down every time Atlantis gets put under water. This is what I have so far: what have I done wrong with my code?

```
// Place your methods here
private void InterfaceLoadFile(Object[] args)
{
    LoadFromFile((string)args[0]);
}

private void InterfaceLoadTileFile(Object[] args)
{
    LoadFromFile((string)args[0],
                 (int)args[1],
                 (int)args[2],
                 (int)args[3],
                 (int)args[4]);
}

private void InterfaceSaveFile(Object[] args)
{
    SaveToFile((string)args[0]);
}

private void InterfaceSaveTileFile(Object[] args)
{
    SaveToFile((string)args[0],
                 (int)args[1],
                 (int)args[2],
                 (int)args[3],
                 (int)args[4]);
}

private void InterfaceBakeTerrain(Object[] args)
{
    UpdateRevertMap();
}

private void InterfaceRevertTerrain(Object[] args)
{
    int x, y;
    for(x = 0; x < m_channel.Width; x++)
        for(y = 0; y < m_channel.Height; y++)
            m_channel[x, y] = m_revert[x, y];

}

private void InterfaceFlipTerrain(Object[] args)
{
    String direction = (String)args[0];

    if (direction.ToLower().StartsWith("y"))
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < m_channel.Width; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < m_channel.Height / 2; y++)
            {
                double height = m_channel[x, y];
                double flippedHeight = m_channel[x, (int)m_channel.Height - 1 - y];
                m_channel[x, y] = flippedHeight;
                m_channel[x, (int)m_channel.Height - 1 - y] = height;

            }
        }
    }
    else if (direction.ToLower().StartsWith("x"))
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < m_channel.Height; y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < m_channel.Width / 2; x++)
            {
                double height = m_channel[x, y];
                double flippedHeight = m_channel[(int)m_channel.Width - 1 - x, y];
                m_channel[x, y] = flippedHeight;
                m_channel[(int)m_channel.Width - 1 - x, y] = height;

            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MainConsole.Instance.OutputFormat("ERROR: Unrecognised direction {0} - need x or y", direction);
    }
}

private void InterfaceRescaleTerrain(Object[] args)
{
    double desiredMin = (double)args[0];
    double desiredMax = (double)args[1];

    // determine desired scaling factor
    double desiredRange = desiredMax - desiredMin;
    //m_log.InfoFormat("Desired {0}, {1} = {2}", new Object[] { desiredMin, desiredMax, desiredRange });

    if (desiredRange == 0d)
    {
        // delta is zero so flatten at requested height
        InterfaceFillTerrain(new Object[] { args[1] });
    }
    else
    {
        //work out current heightmap range
        double currMin = double.MaxValue;
        double currMax = double.MinValue;

        int width = m_channel.Width;
        int height = m_channel.Height;

        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                double currHeight = m_channel[x, y];
                if (currHeight < currMin)
                {
                    currMin = currHeight;
                }
                else if (currHeight > currMax)
                {
                    currMax = currHeight;
                }
            }
        }

        double currRange = currMax - currMin;
        double scale = desiredRange / currRange;

        //m_log.InfoFormat("Current {0}, {1} = {2}", new Object[] { currMin, currMax, currRange });
        //m_log.InfoFormat("Scale = {0}", scale);

        // scale the heightmap accordingly
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                double currHeight = m_channel[x, y] - currMin;
                m_channel[x, y] = desiredMin + (currHeight * scale);
            }
        }

    }

}

private void InterfaceElevateTerrain(Object[] args)
{
    int x, y;
    for(x = 0; x < m_channel.Width; x++)
        for(y = 0; y < m_channel.Height; y++)
            m_channel[x, y] += (double)args[0];
}

private void InterfaceMultiplyTerrain(Object[] args)
{
    int x, y;
    for(x = 0; x < m_channel.Width; x++)
        for(y = 0; y < m_channel.Height; y++)
            m_channel[x, y] *= (double)args[0];
}

private void InterfaceLowerTerrain(Object[] args)
{
    int x, y;
    for(x = 0; x < m_channel.Width; x++)
        for(y = 0; y < m_channel.Height; y++)
            m_channel[x, y] -= (double)args[0];
}

public void InterfaceFillTerrain(Object[] args)
{
    int x, y;

    for(x = 0; x < m_channel.Width; x++)
        for(y = 0; y < m_channel.Height; y++)
            m_channel[x, y] = (double)args[0];
}

private void InterfaceMinTerrain(Object[] args)
{
    int x, y;
    for(x = 0; x < m_channel.Width; x++)
    {
        for(y = 0; y < m_channel.Height; y++)
        {
            m_channel[x, y] = Math.Max((double)args[0], m_channel[x, y]);
        }
    }
}

private void InterfaceMaxTerrain(Object[] args)
{
    int x, y;
    for(x = 0; x < m_channel.Width; x++)
    {
        for(y = 0; y < m_channel.Height; y++)
        {
            m_channel[x, y] = Math.Min((double)args[0], m_channel[x, y]);
        }
    }
}

private void InterfaceShow(Object[] args)
{
    Vector2 point;

    if (!ConsoleUtil.TryParseConsole2DVector((string)args[0], null, out point))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0} is not a valid vector", args[0]);
        return;
    }

    double height = m_channel[(int)point.X, (int)point.Y];

    Console.WriteLine("Terrain height at {0} is {1}", point, height);
}

private void InterfaceShowDebugStats(Object[] args)
{
    double max = Double.MinValue;
    double min = double.MaxValue;
    double sum = 0;

    int x;
    for(x = 0; x < m_channel.Width; x++)
    {
        int y;
        for(y = 0; y < m_channel.Height; y++)
        {
            sum += m_channel[x, y];
            if (max < m_channel[x, y])
                max = m_channel[x, y];
            if (min > m_channel[x, y])
                min = m_channel[x, y];
        }
    }

    double avg = sum / (m_channel.Height * m_channel.Width);

    MainConsole.Instance.OutputFormat("Channel {0}x{1}", m_channel.Width, m_channel.Height);
    MainConsole.Instance.OutputFormat("max/min/avg/sum: {0}/{1}/{2}/{3}", max, min, avg, sum);
}

private void InterfaceEnableExperimentalBrushes(Object[] args)
{
    if ((bool)args[0])
    {
        m_painteffects[StandardTerrainEffects.Revert] = new WeatherSphere();
        m_painteffects[StandardTerrainEffects.Flatten] = new OlsenSphere();
        m_painteffects[StandardTerrainEffects.Smooth] = new ErodeSphere();
    }
    else
    {
        InstallDefaultEffects();
    }
}

private void InterfaceRunPluginEffect(Object[] args)
{
    string firstArg = (string)args[0];

    if (firstArg == "list")
    {
        MainConsole.Instance.Output("List of loaded plugins");
        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, ITerrainEffect> kvp in m_plugineffects)
        {
            MainConsole.Instance.Output(kvp.Key);
        }
        return;
    }

    if (firstArg == "reload")
    {
        LoadPlugins();
        return;
    }

    if (m_plugineffects.ContainsKey(firstArg))
    {
        m_plugineffects[firstArg].RunEffect(m_channel);
    }
    else
    {
        MainConsole.Instance.Output("WARNING: No such plugin effect {0} loaded.", firstArg);
    }
}

private void InstallInterfaces()
{
    Command loadFromFileCommand =
        new Command("load", CommandIntentions.COMMAND_HAZARDOUS, InterfaceLoadFile, "Loads a terrain from a specified file.");
    loadFromFileCommand.AddArgument("filename",
                                    "The file you wish to load from, the file extension determines the loader to be used. Supported extensions include: " +
                                    m_supportedFileExtensions, "String");

    Command saveToFileCommand =
        new Command("save", CommandIntentions.COMMAND_NON_HAZARDOUS, InterfaceSaveFile, "Saves the current heightmap to a specified file.");
    saveToFileCommand.AddArgument("filename",
                                  "The destination filename for your heightmap, the file extension determines the format to save in. Supported extensions include: " +
                                  m_supportedFileExtensions, "String");

    Command loadFromTileCommand =
        new Command("load-tile", CommandIntentions.COMMAND_HAZARDOUS, InterfaceLoadTileFile, "Loads a terrain from a section of a larger file.");
    loadFromTileCommand.AddArgument("filename",
                                    "The file you wish to load from, the file extension determines the loader to be used. Supported extensions include: " +
                                    m_supportedFileExtensions, "String");
    loadFromTileCommand.AddArgument("file width", "The width of the file in tiles", "Integer");
    loadFromTileCommand.AddArgument("file height", "The height of the file in tiles", "Integer");
    loadFromTileCommand.AddArgument("minimum X tile", "The X region coordinate of the first section on the file",
                                    "Integer");
    loadFromTileCommand.AddArgument("minimum Y tile", "The Y region coordinate of the first section on the file",
                                    "Integer");

    Command saveToTileCommand =
        new Command("save-tile", CommandIntentions.COMMAND_HAZARDOUS, InterfaceSaveTileFile, "Saves the current heightmap to the larger file.");
    saveToTileCommand.AddArgument("filename",
                                    "The file you wish to save to, the file extension determines the loader to be used. Supported extensions include: " +
                                    m_supportFileExtensionsForTileSave, "String");
    saveToTileCommand.AddArgument("file width", "The width of the file in tiles", "Integer");
    saveToTileCommand.AddArgument("file height", "The height of the file in tiles", "Integer");
    saveToTileCommand.AddArgument("minimum X tile", "The X region coordinate of the first section on the file",
                                    "Integer");
    saveToTileCommand.AddArgument("minimum Y tile", "The Y region coordinate of the first tile on the file\n"
                                  + "= Example =\n"
                                  + "To save a PNG file for a set of map tiles 2 regions wide and 3 regions high from map co-ordinate (9910,10234)\n"
                                  + "        # terrain save-tile ST06.png 2 3 9910 10234\n",
                                  "Integer");

    // Terrain adjustments
    Command fillRegionCommand =
        new Command("fill", CommandIntentions.COMMAND_HAZARDOUS, InterfaceFillTerrain, "Fills the current heightmap with a specified value.");
    fillRegionCommand.AddArgument("value", "The numeric value of the height you wish to set your region to.",
                                  "Double");

    Command elevateCommand =
        new Command("elevate", CommandIntentions.COMMAND_HAZARDOUS, InterfaceElevateTerrain, "Raises the current heightmap by the specified amount.");
    elevateCommand.AddArgument("amount", "The amount of height to add to the terrain in meters.", "Double");

    Command lowerCommand =
        new Command("lower", CommandIntentions.COMMAND_HAZARDOUS, InterfaceLowerTerrain, "Lowers the current heightmap by the specified amount.");
    lowerCommand.AddArgument("amount", "The amount of height to remove from the terrain in meters.", "Double");

    Command multiplyCommand =
        new Command("multiply", CommandIntentions.COMMAND_HAZARDOUS, InterfaceMultiplyTerrain, "Multiplies the heightmap by the value specified.");
    multiplyCommand.AddArgument("value", "The value to multiply the heightmap by.", "Double");

    Command bakeRegionCommand =
        new Command("bake", CommandIntentions.COMMAND_HAZARDOUS, InterfaceBakeTerrain, "Saves the current terrain into the regions revert map.");
    Command revertRegionCommand =
        new Command("revert", CommandIntentions.COMMAND_HAZARDOUS, InterfaceRevertTerrain, "Loads the revert map terrain into the regions heightmap.");

    Command flipCommand =
        new Command("flip", CommandIntentions.COMMAND_HAZARDOUS, InterfaceFlipTerrain, "Flips the current terrain about the X or Y axis");
    flipCommand.AddArgument("direction", "[x|y] the direction to flip the terrain in", "String");

    Command rescaleCommand =
        new Command("rescale", CommandIntentions.COMMAND_HAZARDOUS, InterfaceRescaleTerrain, "Rescales the current terrain to fit between the given min and max heights");
    rescaleCommand.AddArgument("min", "min terrain height after rescaling", "Double");
    rescaleCommand.AddArgument("max", "max terrain height after rescaling", "Double");

    Command minCommand = new Command("min", CommandIntentions.COMMAND_HAZARDOUS, InterfaceMinTerrain, "Sets the minimum terrain height to the specified value.");
    minCommand.AddArgument("min", "terrain height to use as minimum", "Double");

    Command maxCommand = new Command("max", CommandIntentions.COMMAND_HAZARDOUS, InterfaceMaxTerrain, "Sets the maximum terrain height to the specified value.");
    maxCommand.AddArgument("min", "terrain height to use as maximum", "Double");


    // Debug
    Command showDebugStatsCommand =
        new Command("stats", CommandIntentions.COMMAND_STATISTICAL, InterfaceShowDebugStats,
                    "Shows some information about the regions heightmap for debugging purposes.");

    Command showCommand =
        new Command("show", CommandIntentions.COMMAND_NON_HAZARDOUS, InterfaceShow,
                    "Shows terrain height at a given co-ordinate.");
    showCommand.AddArgument("point", "point in <x>,<y> format with no spaces (e.g. 45,45)", "String");

    Command experimentalBrushesCommand =
        new Command("newbrushes", CommandIntentions.COMMAND_HAZARDOUS, InterfaceEnableExperimentalBrushes,
                    "Enables experimental brushes which replace the standard terrain brushes. WARNING: This is a debug setting and may be removed at any time.");
    experimentalBrushesCommand.AddArgument("Enabled?", "true / false - Enable new brushes", "Boolean");

    // Plugins
    Command pluginRunCommand =
        new Command("effect", CommandIntentions.COMMAND_HAZARDOUS, InterfaceRunPluginEffect, "Runs a specified plugin effect");
    pluginRunCommand.AddArgument("name", "The plugin effect you wish to run, or 'list' to see all plugins", "String");



    m_commander.RegisterCommand("multiply", multiplyCommand);

    m
    // Add this to our scene so scripts can call these functions
    m_scene.RegisterModuleCommander(m_commander);

    // Add Modify command to Scene, since Command object requires fixed-length arglists
    m_scene.AddCommand("Terrain", this, "terrain modify",
                       "terrain modify <operation> <value> [<area>] [<taper>]",
                       "Modifies the terrain as instructed." +
                       "\nEach operation can be limited to an area of effect:" +
                       "\n * -ell=x,y,rx[,ry] constrains the operation to an ellipse centred at x,y" +
                       "\n * -rec=x,y,dx[,dy] constrains the operation to a rectangle based at x,y" +
                       "\nEach operation can have its effect tapered based on distance from centre:" +
                       "\n * elliptical operations taper as cones" +
                       "\n * rectangular operations taper as pyramids"
                       ,
                       ModifyCommand);

}

public void InterfaceMultiplyTerrain(Object[] args)
{
    int x, y;
    for (x = 0; x < m_channel.Width; x++)
        for (y = 0; y < m_channel.Height; y++)
            m_channel[x, y] *= (double)args[0];
}

private void InstallInterfaces()
{


    Command multiplyCommand =
        new Command("multiply", CommandIntentions.COMMAND_HAZARDOUS, InterfaceMultiplyTerrain, "Multiplies the heightmap by the value specified.");
    multiplyCommand.AddArgument("value", "The value to multiply the heightmap by.", "Double");



    // Debug
    Command showDebugStatsCommand =
        new Command("stats", CommandIntentions.COMMAND_STATISTICAL, InterfaceShowDebugStats,
                    "Shows some information about the regions heightmap for debugging purposes.");


    // Plugins
    Command pluginRunCommand =
        new Command("effect", CommandIntentions.COMMAND_HAZARDOUS, InterfaceRunPluginEffect, "Runs a specified plugin effect");
    pluginRunCommand.AddArgument("name", "The plugin effect you wish to run, or 'list' to see all plugins", "String");



    m_commander.RegisterCommand("multiply", multiplyCommand);


    // Add this to our scene so scripts can call these functions
    m_scene.RegisterModuleCommander(m_commander);

    // Add Modify command to Scene, since Command object requires fixed-length arglists
    m_scene.AddCommand("Terrain", this, "terrain modify",
                       "terrain modify <operation> <value> [<area>] [<taper>]",
                       "Modifies the terrain as instructed." +
                       "\nEach operation can be limited to an area of effect:" +
                       "\n * -ell=x,y,rx[,ry] constrains the operation to an ellipse centred at x,y" +
                       "\n * -rec=x,y,dx[,dy] constrains the operation to a rectangle based at x,y" +
                       "\nEach operation can have its effect tapered based on distance from centre:" +
                       "\n * elliptical operations taper as cones" +
                       "\n * rectangular operations taper as pyramids"
                       ,
                       ModifyCommand);

}

public void UpdateTerrainWithTide()
{
            InterfaceMultiplyTerrain(0.95);
            multiplyCommand = 0.95;
            multiplyCommand(0.95);
   }

public void ModifyCommand(string module, string[] cmd)
{
    string result;
    Scene scene = SceneManager.Instance.CurrentScene;
    if ((scene != null) && (scene != m_scene))
    {
        result = String.Empty;
    }
    else if (cmd.Length > 2)
    {
        string operationType = cmd[2];


        ITerrainModifier operation;
        if (!m_modifyOperations.TryGetValue(operationType, out operation))
        {
            result = String.Format("Terrain Modify \"{0}\" not found.", operationType);
        }
        else if ((cmd.Length > 3) && (cmd[3] == "usage"))
        {
            result = "Usage: " + operation.GetUsage();
        }
        else
        {
            result = operation.ModifyTerrain(m_channel, cmd);
        }

        if (result == String.Empty)
        {
            result = "Modified terrain";
            m_log.DebugFormat("Performed terrain operation {0}", operationType);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result = "Usage: <operation-name> <arg1> <arg2>...";
    }
    if (result != String.Empty)
    {
        MainConsole.Instance.Output(result);
    }
}




public void TideUpdate ()
{
    ulong timeStamp;
    double cyclePos; //cycles from 0.0000000001 to 0.999999999999
    double cycleRadians;
    double tideRange;
    double tideMiddle;
    string tideLevelMsg;

    if (((m_frame++ % m_frameUpdateRate) != 0) || !m_ready) {
        return;
    }
    timeStamp = (ulong) (DateTime.Now.Ticks);

    cyclePos = (double)(timeStamp % (m_cycleTime * TICKS_PER_SECOND)) / (m_cycleTime * TICKS_PER_SECOND);
    cycleRadians = cyclePos * Math.PI * 2;

    if (cyclePos < 0.5) m_tideDirection = false; else m_tideDirection = true;

    if (m_tideDirection != m_lastTideDirection)
    { //if the tide changes re-calculate the tide times
        if (cyclePos < 0.5)
        { // tide just changed to be high->low
            m_lowTideTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds((double)(m_cycleTime * (0.5 - cyclePos)));
            m_highTideTime = m_lowTideTime.AddSeconds((double)(m_cycleTime / 2));
            m_tideAnnounceMsg = "High Tide";
        }
        else
        {   //tide just changed to be low->high
            m_highTideTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds((double)(m_cycleTime * (1.0 - cyclePos)));
            m_lowTideTime = m_highTideTime.AddSeconds((double)(m_cycleTime / 2));
            m_tideAnnounceMsg = "Low Tide";
        }
        m_lastTideDirection = m_tideDirection;
    }
    tideRange = (double) (m_highTide - m_lowTide) / 2;
    tideMiddle = (double) m_lowTide + tideRange;
    m_tideLevel = (float) (Math.Cos(cycleRadians) * tideRange + tideMiddle);

    tideLevelMsg = "Current Server Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("T") + "\n";
    tideLevelMsg += "Current Tide Level: " + m_tideLevel.ToString() + "\n";
    tideLevelMsg += "Low Tide Time: " + m_lowTideTime.ToString("T") + "\n";
    tideLevelMsg += "Low Tide Level: " + m_lowTide.ToString() + "\n";
    tideLevelMsg += "High Tide Time: " + m_highTideTime.ToString("T") + "\n";
    tideLevelMsg += "High Tide Level: " + m_highTide.ToString() + "\n";
    tideLevelMsg += "Tide Direction: " + ((m_tideDirection) ? "Coming In" : "Going Out") + "\n";
    tideLevelMsg += "Cycle Position: " + cyclePos.ToString() + "\n";
    if (m_tideAnnounceMsg != "")
    {
        if (m_tideAnnounceCounter++ > m_tideAnnounceCount)
        {
            m_tideAnnounceCounter = 0;
            m_tideAnnounceMsg = "";
        }
        else
        {
            tideLevelMsg += "Tide Warning: " + m_tideAnnounceMsg + "\n";
        }
    }

    if (m_tideInfoDebug) m_log.InfoFormat("[{0}]: Sea Level currently at {1}m in Region: {2}", m_name, m_tideLevel, m_scene.RegionInfo.RegionName);

    if (m_tideInfoBroadcast && m_tideDirection)
    {
        m_scene.SimChatBroadcast(Utils.StringToBytes(tideLevelMsg), ChatTypeEnum.Region, m_tideInfoChannel, m_shoutPos, "TIDE", UUID.Zero, false);
        m_scene.SimChatBroadcast(Utils.StringToBytes(m_tideLevel.ToString()), ChatTypeEnum.Region, m_tideLevelChannel, m_shoutPos, "TIDE", UUID.Zero, false);
    }
    if (m_tideInfoDebug) m_log.InfoFormat("[{0}]: Updating Region: {1}", m_name, m_scene.RegionInfo.RegionName);

    m_scene.RegionInfo.RegionSettings.WaterHeight = m_tideLevel;
    m_scene.EventManager.TriggerRequestChangeWaterHeight(m_tideLevel);
    m_scene.EventManager.TriggerTerrainTick();

    if (m_tideInfoBroadcast && !m_tideDirection)
    {
        m_scene.SimChatBroadcast(Utils.StringToBytes(tideLevelMsg), ChatTypeEnum.Region, m_tideInfoChannel, m_shoutPos, "TIDE", UUID.Zero, false);
        m_scene.SimChatBroadcast(Utils.StringToBytes(m_tideLevel.ToString()), ChatTypeEnum.Region, m_tideLevelChannel, m_shoutPos, "TIDE", UUID.Zero, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never used OpenSim so I'm not sure entirely how to use it but I do notice that none of these methods ever reference `m_tideLevel` or     `m_scene.RegionInfo.RegionSettings.WaterHeight` so how does anything know to do anything when the water level reaches any limit?

Comment: Please try to post a ["Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This is a lot of code (590 lines) with no clues what you have specific problems with. "What is wrong with my code?" questions need more information - What have you tried to solve the problem? What are you trying to achieve? Do you get any error messages? Is there any debug information that helps readers to know where to start looking? Please edit your question to include more information.

Answer (score 0):

suggestion - start searching the code for the ossl implementations then reverse engineer them to work out how the terrain works. Basically it's modifying a bitmap (i think) then when flushed the difference is streamed to the client.

https://github.com/opensim/opensim/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=osSetTerrainHeight

scripted version:

```
default
 {
   touch_start()
   {
    osSetTerrainHeight(40, 101, 21.4);
    osTerrainFlush();
    }
 }
```